# vimeo and javascript (froogaloop) - get video information

Tags: javascript, video, vimeo

I have this really simple code. And i've some problems with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
  <!--
  <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/vimeo/player-api/master/javascript/froogaloop.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <iframe
        id="vimeo_1"
        src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/7100569?api=1&player_id=test"
        width="400"
        height="225"
        frameborder="0">
    </iframe>

    <a id="play" href="javascript:void(0)">play</a>
    <a id="pause" href="javascript:void(0)">pause</a>
    <a id="mute" href="javascript:void(0)">mute</a>
    <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0.5" step="0.01" />
    <a id="videoInfo" href="javascript:void(0)">video info</a>

    <div>
        <ul id="showVideoInfo">
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="debug"></div>

    <script>
    var v1 = document.getElementById('vimeo_1');
    var play = document.getElementById('play');
    var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
    var mute = document.getElementById('mute');
    var volume = document.getElementById('volume');
    var videoInfo = document.getElementById('videoInfo');

    var debug = document.getElementById('debug');

    $f(v1).addEvent('ready', function(pID){
        console.log('ready');
    });

    addEvent(play, 'click', playVideo);
    addEvent(pause, 'click', pauseVideo);
    addEvent(mute, 'click', muteVideo);
    addEvent(volume, 'change', volumeVideo);
    addEvent(videoInfo, 'click', infoVideo);

    function addEvent(obj, name, callback) {
        if (obj.addEventListener)
            obj.addEventListener(name, callback, false);
        else
            obj.attachEvent(name, callback, false);
    }

    function playVideo() {
        console.log('play');
        $f(v1).api('play');
    }

    function pauseVideo() {
        console.log('pause');
        $f(v1).api('pause');
    }

    function muteVideo() {
        console.log('mute');
        $f(v1).api('setVolume', 0);
    }

    function volumeVideo() {
        console.log(this.value);
        $f(v1).api('setVolume', this.value);
    }

    function infoVideo() {
        console.log('videoInfo: ');
        $f(v1).api('paused', function(v) {
            console.log(v);
        });
    }
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

First of all, buttons like PLAY, PAUSE, MUTE and the volume slider (webkit only) works fine.
But when i need to get some video data from video and print somewhere (console, for example) nothing works and a message like that is shown:

[image: ERROR in Chrome]

Searching around here i've found some question about that, but everithing that works for them simply not work for me. argh!

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because you are playing your video as a local file. You have to run your code on a web server (even locally with MAMP or WAMP).

Ken.